# Winter 18 release - Lightning Service Console and Live Agent

Tags: lightning-experience, liveagent

I am looking at 
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter18/release-notes/rn_live_agent_lex_gaps.htm

The release documentation says-

> You must route chats with Omni-Channel to chat in Lightning
>   Experience. Make sure you have Omni-Channel ready for Lightning
>   Experience and have set up your chat button to route with
>   Omni-Channel. Considerations for Omni-Channel routing for chats apply.

Does that mean to be able to use Live-agent in lightning console , omni-channel must be configured and enabled ?
If I don't have need for omni-channel but do need live-agent, does that mean i have to stick with Service Console Classic ?

Answer (score 1):

It means you'll be able to use Live Agent but you need to route the Live Agent Chats with omni-channel routing. Basically you'll need to have Live Agent Configured and then configure omni-channel.

Since you already have Live Agent, Salesforce will create a routing channel for you called Live Agent. Use it for the presence status definition. In the chat button select `omni` option instead of routing by skill and in the queue select the `Live Chat Transcript` object and `Live Agent Session`